# Codeigniter can't login

Tags: php

Here is the controller, when I click the login button, nothing happens. What I want is to load the success screen when user data is validated and show error messages when user data is not validated.

I have set my base_controller as Login

```
<?php

    class Login extends CI_Controller {
        /**  
         * 
         * load the magazines
         */

        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->model('User','National_Holiday','Updated_Holiday');
        }
        public function index() {
            $this->load->view('login');
        }

        /**  
         * 
         * add a magazine
         */

        public function login(){

            $this->form_validation->set_rules(array (
               array(
                  'field'  => 'username',
                   'label' => 'username',
                   'rules' => 'required',
               ) ,
                array(
                  'field'  => 'password',
                    'label' => 'password',
                    'rules' => 'required|is_numeric',
                ),

            ));

            $this -> form_validation ->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error">','</div>');
            if(!$this->form_validation->run()){

               $this->load->view('login');
            }
           else {

               $this->load->view('national_holiday_screen');
           }
        }
}
```

here is the view

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<form method="post">
    <!--  LOGIN DIV STARTS HERE -->
<div>
    <div> <h2> Log In </h2></div>
    <div>
        <lablel for="username"> Username </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password"> Password </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
</div>
     <!--  LOGIN DIV ENDS HERE -->
</form>
```

When I click the login button, nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where do you specify the form submission url?

Comment: I am new to codeigniter, i have no idea.i am just following tutorials

Comment: @Wold please suggest me something, what i need to change

Comment: [this link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) explains form_open(), a helper method for initiating a form.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give action attribute in form tag, like this:
action="http://yoursitename.com/controllername"
in your case controllername is login.

For more help, you can refer:
[https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html][1]

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

[this link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) shows how `form_open()` works, one of codeigniter's utility functions from the form helper libary.

In your case you would want this line of code:

```
 <?php echo form_open('/login'); ?>
```

or something that you want to be the login url.

This line would replace

```
<form method="post">
```

in your html and when rendered would be something like

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" action="http:/example.com/index.php/login" />
```

If you aren't familiar with URI routing, then you should read about that here](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html). I would recommedn setting up a route for you login, but the default format for a url is

```
example.com/class/function/id/
```

so yours  might look like

```
example.com/login/login
```

And `form_open()` would then look like (even though its kind of cluncky)

```
<?php echo form_open('/login/login'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

login.php controller file

```
<?php

    class Login extends CI_Controller {
        /**  
         * 
         * load the magazines
         */

        function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('User','National_Holiday','Updated_Holiday');
        }
        public function index() {
            $this->load->view('login');
    }

        /**  
         * 
         * add a magazine
         */

        public function validate(){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules(array (
               array(
                  'field'  => 'username',
                   'label' => 'username',
                   'rules' => 'required',
               ) ,
                array(
                  'field'  => 'password',
                    'label' => 'password',
                    'rules' => 'required|is_numeric',
                ),

            ));
      $this -> form_validation ->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-error">','</div>');
            if(!$this->form_validation->run()){

               $this->load->view('login');
            }
           else {

               $this->load->view('national_holiday_screen');
           }
        }
}
```

Here I have loaded one helper to give action url in view file

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Also I have changed function name from login to validate as function name should not be similar to class name as constructor is already defined there

login.php view file

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<form method="post" action = "<?php echo site_url("login/validate"); ?>">
    <!--  LOGIN DIV STARTS HERE -->
<div>
    <div> <h2> Log In </h2></div>
    <div>
        <lablel for="username"> Username </label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password"> Password </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value=""/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Login">
    </div>
</div>
     <!--  LOGIN DIV ENDS HERE -->
</form>
```

Hope this will help you